# See SML full list

Tags: sml

Is there any way to print full list using SML?

Usually what happen is in SML when I have too many elements it prints first few elements separated by "," and then it omits the rest of the list with `...` but I want to see the full list. Is there any way to do that?

```
val a =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,18,19,20]
```

then If i write on REPL `a` it returns something like:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,...]
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you are using SML/NJ.

What you wan't to customize is the reference values in [Control.Print](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/Compiler/pages/printcontrol.html). In this case you wan't to change the value of `printLength` to something larger, for example

```
Control.Print.printLength := 100;
```

In general it is the `print*` references you wan't to change. However for strings, they chose to call it `stringDepth`, for some reason.

---

Assuming that you are using MosML.

From the [Moscow ML Language Overview](http://www.itu.dk/people/sestoft/mosml/mosmlref.pdf), it is described that the Meta unit exposes these two functions (to "control the interactive system")

```
val printDepth : int ref  (* limit printed data depth *)
val printLength : int ref (* limit printed list and vector length *)
```

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are using Poly/ML. The function `PolyML.print_depth` says how deep printing should go in any structure (lists included). Change it to something larger:

```
PolyML.print_depth 500
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much.  Do you know somewhere where you can find the full documentation for the PolyML signature?  I've googled a fair amount but can't find anything, even on the PolyML website!

Comment: @CharlieSeymour Unfortunately not. I haven't used PolyML since I wrote this answer so you are better off googling. I found at least these two links that looks promising: http://www.lfcs.inf.ed.ac.uk/software/polyml/docs/Intro1.html and http://polyml.org/docs/PrettyPrint.html

Comment: Alas, much of it seems outdated.  Thanks for trying anyway!

Comment: One thing we used to do when using SML/NJ was poking around in the code. It is open source after all. A lot of ambiguities in the documentation was answered that way.

Answer (score 0):

This output is only for debugging and while is convenient, is not a proper way to do so (you don't get this from running an executable if you generate it). To print out all elements independent of print limit set in ML prompt of your choice, you can do following:

```
fun listToString [] = "[]\n"
|   listToString (c::l) =
        "[" ^ (Int.toString c)
        ^ foldl (fn (s1, s2) => s2 ^ ", " ^ s1) "" (map (Int.toString) l)
        ^ "]\n"
val _  = print (listToString a)
```

Comment: A simpler implementation utilising the standard library would be `fun listToString l = "[" ^ String.concatWith ", " (List.map Int.toString l) ^ "]"`.