# Sml parsing a csv file?

Tags: parsing, sml

These are the functions I have defined (the other functions used inside are tested and they work fine):

qstring : accepts a string that does not contain the double quote character (").

```
val qstring : string parser = (many (sat (fn c => not (c = #"\"")))) >>= (fn cs => 
          return (String.implode cs))
```

sepBy : a parser that takes a parser that takes two parsers as inputs; the
        first one matches the separator, and the second one matches the
        content.

```
val sepBy1 = fn s => fn p => p >>= (fn v1 => many (s >>= (fn _ => 
                 p >>= (fn v2 => return v2))) >>= (fn v2 => 
                             return (v1::v2)))

val sepBy = fn s => fn p => (sepBy1 s p) +++ (return [])

val csvline : record parser = sepBy1 (ch #",") field >>= 
                             (fn l => newline >>= (fn _ => return l))

val csvfile : csvfile parser = many csvline
```

Input example:

```
val csvEx = "\"John Smith\",72,1782,\"Colon, Cristobal\"\n198,2,3,4,5,64434,\"two\"\n"
```

I get # in place of where the strings should be parsed. Any hints?

```
- parse csvfile csvEx;
val it =
SOME
    ([[String #,Number #,Number #,String #],
     [Number #,Number #,Number #,Number #,Number #,Number #,
     String #]],"") : (csvfile * string) option
```

Comment: Also note that there is a `printLength`, that controls length of printed lists. See [this QA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412439/see-sml-full-list/14412827) for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using SML/NJ here. This is just a limit of NJ's pretty printer. Setting

```
Control.Print.printDepth := 20  (* or whatever *)
```

should lift it.